# Tilemap Shader: how to correctly apply effect to the tiles when player is near them within a specific range

Tags: shader, game-development, godot, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I want to apply some sort of effect when the player is near the tiles of a specific TileMap when the tiles are within a specified range, for example, the classic transparency when the player is behind an object.

I took inspiration from this video: [shader video](https://youtu.be/j9YdKqTmQtY?t=557), but I'm having problem to center the shader effect at the player position and, from the GIF below, it seems to respond to the camera more than the player position.

[image]

by the way, this is the shader code: (vec(320., 180.)... is an offset to actually see the effect, otherwise it would be seen even further away from the player)

```
shader_type canvas_item;

uniform vec2 player_pos = vec2(0.);
uniform float range = 200.;

varying vec2 screen_pos;

void vertex() {
    screen_pos = (WORLD_MATRIX * vec4(VERTEX, 1., 1.)).xy - (vec2(320., 180.) + range/2.);
}

void fragment() {
    float distance_to_player = distance(screen_pos, player_pos);
    
    vec4 color = texture(TEXTURE, UV);
    if(distance_to_player > range) {
        color.a *= 1.;
    }
    else {
        color.a *= 0.2;
    }
    COLOR = color;
}
```

And this is the player position that I pass to the shader:

```
crossable_tilemap.material.set_shader_param("player_pos", player.get_global_transform_with_canvas().origin)
```

It's quite hard to debug shaders in Godot, but I'm pretty sure that the problem is finding the right position to pass to the uniform shader and the correct screen_pos to compute in the shader.

Problem that could be caused by the different location of the room scene, containing the tilemap, and the player scene, so I explain a little bit about the structure of the SceenTree:

There is my RootNode: World with three child:
DynamicCameraComponent;
LevelComponent;
Player.
In the LevelComponent will be instanciated the starting room (RoomComponent) with tha adjacent rooms concatenated all together by the RoomLinkerComponent. In the RoomComponent there is the TileMap with the shader.

Does anyone know how to deal with this problem? because, as I said, it is very difficult to debug shaders in godot plus I don't consider myself a shader expert.

Thanks